# How to find the Expected height of a randomly built binary tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, binary-trees, average-case

I would like to find out the Expected height of a binary tree where the insertions are based on a random function. I.e. for each node I visit, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of choosing right or left. I know that the following property holds for height $h$, but it's difficult to add the probability:$$h_{tree}= 1+max(h_{left}, h_{right})$$I think that this version/random tree differs from the random (search) tree mentioned in CLRS chapter 12.4, where you pick a random element from a sorted list $\{1,\dots, n\}$ and insert based on whether the visited node is greater or less than the inserted element. Because, here we choose each path on each visited node to be random.

Note: the binary tree has all its elements at the leafs and internal nodes are only used for routing (see Figure 1.)

```
//pseudocode
insert(i, tree):
    if at leaf v:
        split(); //Create a parent u and set its children to be the leaf v and element i.
    else:
        int left = random()
        int right = random()
        if (left > right):
            insert(i, left-subtree):
        else:
            insert(i, right-subtree)
```

Figure 1:
[image: example of binary tree]

Comment: does split create a parent with two children (split removes two leaves and adds two new ones)? Or does it create a parent with just one child?

Comment: split is only used when the inserted element ends at a leaf. So, a parent node with two children is created. The first child is the old leaf, and the second child is the newly inserted element.

Comment: Are you looking for a lower and upper bound or exact values?

Comment: The expected height. Due to the probability there is no exact value.

Comment: The [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case) is a well defined exact value. This seems to be what you are searching for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree#Random_split_trees 
If you look at your version and pretend that the leaves are just placeholders, the wikipedia version and yours are the same. $O(\log n)$ is the expected height. If you look into the article you can find even better approximations.

Comment: @plshelp Well, there's a bounty on the table. An answer here would be of value to the community.

Comment: Came from the MahExchange posting. When you split, do you put the old one to the left and the new one to the right, or vice versa? Or it doesn't matter? (You don't distinguish between those two cases?)

Comment: @KayK.Preference would be for old to the left and new to the right, however, either way would be fine.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this question on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060570/how-to-find-the-expected-height-of-a-randomly-built-binary-tree/4541311), which has an answer.